# share MQ Libraries installed on server1 to share on server2 liberty server.xml

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq, websphere-liberty

We have configured WLP and MQ to use JMS messaging. On a server1 where the Liberty Servers and MQ installed we referred the MQ libraries as below and it's working fine. However, we are not sure from server2 when we make connection to MQ we are using client transport type with port number. How to refer the below MQ libraries on the server2 server.xml? Any help or guidance on this? Thanks

server.xml from server1

server2 JMS connection

<properties.wmqJms
transportType="CLIENT"
hostName="Host1"
port="9001"
channel="SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN"
queueManager="QM1"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to copy the file wmq.jmsra.rar to the disk of server2 and then set the path to that file in server.xml using a variable:

```
<variable name="wmqJmsClient.rar.location" value="/path/to/wmq/rar/wmq.jmsra.rar"/>
```

See: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/nd?topic=dmal-deploying-jms-applications-liberty-use-mq-messaging-provider